# count duplicated columns in R

Tags: r

My aim is to count number of unique values in first two columns of my df
Here is my df:

```
> head(dat)
       M1 M2 M3 M4
10_A9  H  H  H  H
10_B6  A  H  B  A
10_B8  H  H  H  B
10_B9  H  H  H  H
10_C1  A  B  B  A
10_C3  H  H  H  H
```

I tried with:

```
> unique(dat[,1:2])
       M1 M2
10_A9  H  H
10_B6  A  H
10_C1  A  B
10_D8  H  A
11_B9  B  A
12_D9  B  H
12_E4     A
```

Then I planned to count nrow(), but the answer is not correct. Where I am going wrong in this simple exercise?

EDIT:
Here is my first two columns of dat (few rows):

```
> a[,1:2]
   M1 M2
10_A9   H  H
10_B6   A  H
10_B8   H  H
10_B9   H  H
10_C1   A  B
10_C3   H  H
10_C4   H  H
10_D5   H  H
10_D7   H  H
10_D8   H  A
10_D11  A  H
10_E6   H  H
11_A3   A  B
11_A7   A  B
11_B1   H  H
11_B3   H  H
11_B7   H  A
11_B9   B  A
11_B11  H  H
11_C1   A  H
11_C8   A  H
11_C9   H  A
11_D3   A  B
11_D4   A  B
```

For above few rows, my desired output is:

```
10_B6   A  H
10_C1   A  B
10_D8   H  A
10_D11  A  H
11_A3   A  B
11_A7   A  B
11_B7   H  A
11_B9   B  A
11_C1   A  H
11_C8   A  H
11_C9   H  A
11_D3   A  B
11_D4   A  B
```

Comment: @Frank: Still, I am getting wrong results..

Comment: Given your sample data above (i.e. `head(dat)`) what is the correct answer?  What is your desired output?

Comment: (Different Frank here.) `lapply(dat[,1:2],function(x) length(unique(x)) )` will count the number of unique values in each of the first two columns. But, yeah, I really have little idea if that's actually what you're looking for based on the question.

Comment: @Frank & Frank: Still I am not getting desired output. Sorry for not completing my question. I want to compare first two columns by rows (dat[1,1] with dat[2,1]...) and find how many rows are unique for first two columns, In the above results, in first row, H and H are duplicates, still appearing in results.

Comment: @Frank: Error in Ops.factor(dat[, 1], dat[, 2]) : level sets of factors are different

Comment: You'll need to illustrate desired output. Nothing above looks like a "count" (which should be an integer).

Comment: @ramesh Your desired result is not making much sense.  Why you have `H H` only one time while other rows are multiple.  May be `rbind(a[with(a, M1!=M2),], unique(a[with(a, M1==M2),]))`

Comment: @akrun: Yes, That was my mistake. Now I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually trying to get below ?  Not sure though.

```
DF <- structure(list(row_n = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("10_A9", "10_B6", "10_B8", "10_B9", 
"10_C1", "10_C3", "10_C4", "10_D11", "10_D5", "10_D7", "10_D8", 
"10_E6", "11_A3", "11_A7", "11_B1", "11_B11", "11_B3", "11_B7", 
"11_B9", "11_C1", "11_C8", "11_C9", "11_D3", "11_D4"), class = "factor"), 
    M1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "H"), class = "factor"), M2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "H"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("row_n", 
"M1", "M2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

# I made up row_n to help compare the result below with your desired output.
subset(DF, M1 != M2)
#     row_n M1 M2
# 2   10_B6  A  H
# 5   10_C1  A  B
# 10  10_D8  H  A
# 11 10_D11  A  H
# 13  11_A3  A  B
# 14  11_A7  A  B
# 17  11_B7  H  A
# 18  11_B9  B  A
# 20  11_C1  A  H
# 21  11_C8  A  H
# 22  11_C9  H  A
# 23  11_D3  A  B
# 24  11_D4  A  B

# Below get you the number of pairs.
nrow(subset(DF, M1 != M2))
[1] 13
```

#### Note

```
# You need to convert columns to character (assuming the dataset is all letters).
# To do so, a concise way is to change all columns to characters:

DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.character).

# Or you could do as @Frank suggested.
```

Comment: @akrun, Eagle eyes!!  That kind of output is interesting... Didn't notice that.  Will leave this here for a while for OP's reference.  May delete later.

Comment: you can keep it.  May be the OP made a mistake

Comment: @KFB: you produced desired output. But, when I repeat, I am hitting with error: `Error in Ops.factor(M1, M2) : level sets of factors are different`

Comment: @ramesh Convert your factors to characters or do something like this:  `subset(DF, as.character(M1) != as.character(M2))`